# Print-screen button not working in Lubunt 14.04.03

Tags: lubuntu, print-screen

Print-Screen button does nothing.  I bound the keys to scrot as suggested by [Vasa](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185294http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2185294).  That did not do anything, but scrot does work from the command prompt.  So then I tried replacing lxsession-default as suggested by [Joern](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lubuntu-default-settings/+bug/1233860).  That did not do anything.  I see at the end of the bug report they say the bug is fixed in 14.04. It is not for me !  Does anyone have any idea why this does not work ?  As far as I can see the key needs to invoke a command in the appropriate environment.  I can't see why this has been giving problems for so many years.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry ...  PrintScreen button is working fine.  I made a silly mistake.

I was immersed in what I was doing on a headless machine through teamviewer.  Teamviewer does not send the PrintScreen key to the remote machine.  It is processed locally.  I just found all the screen shots I tried to get (of the headless client screen !) on the host machine.  To it's credit teamviewer is so good that I forgot that I was using a remote system !